Does querySourceFeatures use/have some buffer?
When I use querySourceFeatures on mvt tiles I get results for features that are out of the current viewport.
Why?
Does it use some buffer around the tiles or does it happen because I am in the middle between two zoom levels so a part of the tile is outside of the viewport but it returns features because tile is partially in the viewport?
How to get only feafures that are within the actual viewport?
